# YouTube API - addEventListener not working

Tags: javascript, youtube-api

I try to track any events YouTube video on my site.
Why this doesn't work?
HTML:

```
<div>
     <iframe id="video-block" width="560" height="315" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/123456?enablejsapi=1 " frameborder="0" allowfullscreen ></iframe>
</div>
```

JS:

```
    var tag = document.createElement('script');

    tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
    var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

    function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady( ) {
        alert("1");
        ytplayer = new YT.Player('video-chia');
        ytplayer.addEventListener('onStateChange', function(e) {
            alert('State change');
        });

    }
```

Answer (score -2):

I have done this in the past. I have implemented the state  change slightly differently though

```
var tag = document.createElement('script');

  tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
  var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
  firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

var player;
  function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('player', {

      videoId: 'M7lc1UVf-VE',
      events: {
        'onReady': onPlayerReady,
        'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
      }
    });

  }

  function onPlayerReady(event) {
    event.target.playVideo();
  }

  var done = false;
  function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
    if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING && !done) {
      setTimeout(stopVideo, 6000);
      done = true;
    }
  }
  function stopVideo() {
    player.stopVideo();
  }
```

Comment: I am curious. What statechanges can one capture with this? Regards

Comment: lol, this code is from the doc of the YouTube API. The least you can do is post the origin of the code... @DOCASAREL see  https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference?hl=fr part: **Getting started**